# jQuery $.inArray() always return -1 with an array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of object, that contain key value pair of columnNames.

when i check if a particular columnName exists it alwayz returns -1

Here is an sample http://jsfiddle.net/trLkt/6/, Help will b appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for *string* values in the `columnModel` array, but you're storing *objects* in it (`columnModel.push({'colName': $(this).text()});`). `$.inArray()` cannot decide by itself to compare against the `colName` property of each array element, it simply compares the value you're searching for against each array element.

Comment: then how should i check if an object exists in that array or not

Comment: You need to add plain strings to that array (`columnModel.push($(this).text())`), or you cannot use `$.inArray()`. If you really need to store objects in the array, you will need to iterate over the array yourself and compare each element's `colName` property.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can do:

Add `strings` to the array instead of `objects` using `.push` (as suggested by @lanzz), then `$.inArray` will work as you expect.

Alternatively, if you do need to store objects within the array (if for example you need to have multiple properties within each object) you would need to iterate over each object and see if the `colName` already exists:

```
    var colExists = false;
    var text = $(this).text();
    $.each(columnModel, function(k, v) {
      if(text == v['colName']) {
        colExists = true;
      }
    });
```

Then change your check from `if(colExists === -1)` to `if(!colExists)`.

**Example**

```
$(function () {
  $('#ddlMain').change(function (event) {
    $('option:selected', $(this)).each(function () {

      var colExists = false;
      var text = $(this).text();

      $.each(columnModel, function(k, v) {
        if(text == v['colName']) {
          colExists = true;
        }
      });

      if(!colExists) {
        columnModel.push({'colName': $(this).text()});
        alert($(this).text() + ' added to columnModel');
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best that can be done.
I am actually using this array with jQuery template plugin to generate a dynamic table header.

Template plugin uses an array of objects so needed an array of objects